# syslog in NSFilemanager delegate method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager, syslog

I am using `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` method for copy operation with `fileManager:shouldCopyItemAtPath:toPath:` and `fileManager:shouldProceedAfterError:copyingItemAtPath:toPath:`
delegate methods of `NSFilemanager`. I am not printing any logs from delegate method.

But on console application(All Messages) I am getting so many logs:

```
reading from FilePath: Is a directory
open on FilePath: No such file or directory
open on FilePath:File exists
Cannot make directory FilePath: File exists
```

Logs are coming because of `fileManager:shouldProceedAfterError:copyingItemAtPath:toPath:` delegate method.
**EDIT:**
Sample of my application:

```
        2534 -[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]
          2534 -[__NSOperationInternal start]
            2533 -[NSDirectoryTraversalOperation main]
              1548 -[NSFilesystemItemCopyOperation _handleFTSEntry:]
                817 setattrlist$UNIX2003
                722 copyfile
                  258 lstatx_np$INODE64
                    258 statx1
                      255 __lstat64_extended
                      2 filesec_set_property
                        2 uuid_copy
                      1 malloc
                        1 malloc_zone_malloc
                          1 szone_malloc_should_clear
                            1 tiny_malloc_from_free_list
      ...
                    7 copyfile_stat
                      3 syslog
                        3 vsyslog
```

`copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` is printing logs using `syslog`. How to redirect **syslog** output?
Can anyone please help me out? [Sample Application for Copy](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o5gp1j8eex1b603/z0Ed1mVFK1)

Comment: Are you sure you are giving the right FilePath ? Because it seems that you are printing the logs with incorrect extension of your path or file.

Comment: I am copying folder and i am not printing any logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got reply from apple support:

> The issue behaves as intended.